# Azure Data factory Dynamic content get month name

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to pull the data from a website through the Azure data factory each month. Is there any way to change the URL for each month with month name through the dynamic content feature?

{{static URL}}/TestFile_October_2020.zip

{{static URL}}/TestFile_November_2019.zip

{{static URL}}/TestFile_December_2020.zip

Comment: Are you asking how to 1) determine the current month, 2) get the month name, and 3) build a string using the month name value?

Comment: As  @Joel Cochran said, do you want to build a query string every month by current month?

Comment: @JoelCochran We want to concatenate static URL part with the current month name and the current year.

Comment: Hi @Vijayaretnam Menakanan  TestFile_November_2019.zip  -> TestFile_November_2020.zip? Is this change right？

Comment: @ Joseph Xu Yes. According to the month and year, we need to generate dynamic content

Comment: @Vijayaretnam Menakanan  Do you have any storage account, like Azure SQL or Azure data lake?

Comment: One point I would make is that this is just ate processing and string manipulation - the fact that it is part of a URL is not really relevant to the question. Like @JosephXu pointed out, you can do this in ADF, but a lookup to a table or even an Azure Function would be simpler to implement.

Comment: Hi @Vijayaretnam Menakanan, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can define an array type variable in ADF pipeline,as follows
`[{"id": 1,"Value": "January"},{"id": 2,"Value": "February"},{"id": 3,"Value": "March"},{"id": 4,"Value": "April"},{"id": 5,"Value": "May"},{"id": 6,"Value": "June"},{"id":7,"Value": "July"},{"id": 8,"Value": "August"},{"id": 9,"Value": "September"},{"id": 10,"Value": "October"},{"id": 11,"Value": "November"},{"id": 12,"Value":"December"}]`

1. We can define several variables previously.

[image]

2. Then we can foreach the `Array` variable.

[image]

3. In the ForEach activity, we can store `@item().value` in variable `MonthString`

[image]

4. Then at If Condition activity, we can use `@equals(item().id,int(subString(utcnow(),5,2)))` to select the value of the current month. Here we need to use `int()` function to convert the string type to int type.

[image]

5. Then we can set a Web activity in True activities. We can use `@concat(variables('BasicURL'),concat('/TestFile_',variables('MonthString')),concat('_',substring(utcnow(),0,4),'.zip'))` to build the query string.

[image]

6. The output like this:

[image]

If you have Azure SQL, you can create a table to store this Array and use Lookup activity to find the Value, it will be easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function "formatDateTime" with format 'MMMM' for getting full month name in Dynamic Content. You can refer [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for the same.